# How to use `extends` on any subclass of a known baseclass?

Tags: typescript

We can write our own method in TypeScript to extend a known type `class A`. After extension, instance of a new type will have correct type and both fields `a` and `e` accessible via type system:

```js
class A {
  a = "a";
}

function extend(originalType: typeof A){
  return class extends originalType {
    e = "e"
  }
}

const ExtA = extend(A);
const extA = new ExtA();
console.log(extA.a, extA.e); // both .a and .e are accessible.
```

If we try to extend subclass `class B` using same function declaration, clearly, field `b` will not be available in type system:

```
// continued...
class B extends A {
  b = "b";
}

const ExtB = extend(B);
const extB = new ExtB();
console.log(extB.a, extB.b, extB.e); // Property 'b' does not exist on type '(Anonymous class)'
```

This is TS Playground [link](https://tsplay.dev/N92k1m)

I have tried to write a method `extend2` and `extend3` that would work on any subclass of `A`, but without any success.

This were two attempts, using generics and both resulting in TS compilation errors:

```js
// A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'.
function extend2<T extends typeof A>(subclassType: T) {
    return class extends subclassType {
    e = "e"
  }
}

// Class '(Anonymous class)' incorrectly extends base class 'T'.
  '(Anonymous class)' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'
function extend3<T extends A>(subclassType: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
      return class extends subclassType {
    e = "e"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in TypeScript at this point (v5.3.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making `extend` generic as you did with `extend2`:

```
function extend<ClassType extends typeof A>(originalType: ClassType) {
  return class extends originalType {
    e = "e";
  };
}
```

...but as you discovered, **just** doing that gives you this error on the `return class extends...` statement:

> A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'

To fix that, give `A` a constructor with a single rest parameter of type `any[]`:

```
class A {
  constructor(...args: any[]) {} // <== Needed for `extend` above
  a = "a";
}
```

With those changes, your example works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQB0VYeA5hAFzRiYCeA2gLoCUiAvtAD0g6AB4AvOOgA5AKayAJougAzUtAAGsgB45ZmBRugAjWSHQB3FM2hSARGDsBuJHyRIVBTMQCWWaDp6BqIAwuBQACqsAA6yAbr6CjA4MbLoKnAAfGSkPrQ+mGAgUbFMYZAQJbK8yKh4sjgEeJho4TCBiTC5+YXFqYjWqHH2ss7WfC5uSBjYONAAorrwUh0GZLDcLjO48TjL0JiyFgtLZJvTWBDoILIU5rRkgbAUYAA0u8-VLtNt0ABCu06cAGqGMtmgdmMYym2zmixwAJWCTWf3OsN2iIORxOCLOW0u11u90euj+L3egTJxgppIoXyQQA)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! In one of the iterations of code I've had an error related to `...args` of `constructor` of anonymous `class extends...` and I still wasn't able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
type Class<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T }

function extend<T extends Class<A>>(originalType: T){
  return class extends originalType {
    e = "e"
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pmgXmgIjNg3EgL5JIAuAngA4Cm0AwuFADwAqAfJotAHY0DuACgB0osACcA5hABcaHhQDaAXQCUc1tBJIAZgFcewMgEsA9j2g0AHmRo8AJm0s279mI0gRmsdu0GnxY0ljHjAQVmoaDVVkVHEaMj1xC1BPZ1sHGACgkLCI2kQUVEsubBpsIpJtYHMIMmgAURt4LGsM+0FYVUIanjr0lt4BRubBbqReiFMQGmEQU0lBNthhMAAaAeEaDeXhYHGJphgAIXTXGHhY6AAjUuuCYlJJ+qayU9aXB0Fj8ef096G-BGbzGPVq01m80WbWOqx2Nlh13hby2yNh+0IpCAA)

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice helper/utility type!